# How I can see all the queries executed and classes or methods in my gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gemfile, rails-console

I´m newbie in RoR and I would like to know how I can do two things in Rails (both versions 2 and 3):

1. How I can see all queries generated to database (save, update, find, etc.) in the console of the server?
2. How I can see all the classes and methods of gems included in my Gemfile?

   For example how I can see classes and methods of CanCan, Devise and so on.

   ```
   gem "devise"
   gem "cancan"
   gem "rolify"
   gem "sass-rails"
   ```

And so on...

Sorry for my english and thank in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rails folder there will be a log sub-folder. Depending on where your application is running and on your configurations you'll be able to see something similar to a development.log, staging.log or production.log file in that folder.

Also the `.to_sql` method can be used to show the sql. e.g.

`User.where(:id => 29).to_sql` will yield the following:

```
"SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 29"
```

For viewing gems. In terminal type `bundle show devise` this will return you a path. Go to that path. All the necessary code will be present over there.

`/home/sohaib/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@moviepass/gems/devise-1.4.9`

Comment: I tried it but (undefined method `to_sql' for #<Ticket) to Ticket.find(params[:id]).to_sql And  (undefined method `to_sql' for true:TrueClass) to @ticket.update_attributes(params[:ticket]).to_sql
thank in advance!!!

Comment: That is because .find will return an object(Ticket in this case) and update_attribute will return a true or false. to_sql can be used when an ActiveRecord::Relation is being returned.

Comment: Thank!!.. But how i can see the query on the methods save and update_attributes?? That is it possible?? Thank again